# If $\gcd(n,m)=1$, show that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Assume that $\gcd(n,m)=1$, and show that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic. (Hint: show that (1,1) is the generator.)

We are suggested to use the Chinese remainder to prove this. However, I am not sure how to go about this. Any suggestions will be helpful!

Comment: Do you know how to calculate orders in direct products?

Comment: Not sure how to calculate orders in direct products. But the order of (1,1) should be mn?. Thus, by a theorem(an element a of z/nz is a generator if and only if it has order n), (1,1) generates z/nz x z/mz. Is this a correct route?

Comment: In general, the order of a tupule in a direct product is equal to the least common multiple of the individual orders of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
For any integer $a$, working in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$,

$$a (1,1) = (0,0) \iff 
(a,a) = (0,0) \iff
n \mid a \text{ and } m \mid a.$$

Now that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, what does that tell you?

**Possibly helpful fact:** If $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime and they divide some integer $k$, then $mn$ divides the integer $k$.

**Another possibly helpful fact:** The **"order"** of an element is the smallest $k$ such that $k$ times that element (i.e. add itself $k$ times) is $0$. In this case, we have just proven that the order of $a$ is $mn$.
If the order of an element $x$ is $k$, then all the elements $x, 2x, 3x, 4x, \ldots, (k-1)x, kx$ are different. If you can accept those facts, that should get you close to what you want to prove.

Comment: I'm not too sure. The fact that gcd(n,m)=1 tells us that 1 is the only integer that divides both of them. Thus, 1 must be the generator ?

Comment: @Monica I added some more possibly helpful facts! The first helpful fact should answer your comment.

Comment: I think I was able to put together the proof. Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: @Monica You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Show the natural mapping
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z &\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z \\
x&\longmapsto (x\bmod m,x\bmod n)
\end{align}
is a ring homomorphism and that it is surjective (use *Bézout's identity*).

What is its kernel?

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese Remainder Theorem states that, if $m$ and $n$ are coprime, then, for any $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, the system of congruences
\begin{cases}
x\equiv a\pmod{n}\\[4px]
x\equiv b\pmod{m}
\end{cases}
has a solution.

Let $(a+n\mathbb{Z},b+m\mathbb{Z})\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$; by the CRT, there is $x$ such that
$$
(x+n\mathbb{Z},x+m\mathbb{Z})=(a+n\mathbb{Z},b+m\mathbb{Z})
$$
Now observe that $(x+n\mathbb{Z},x+m\mathbb{Z})=x(1+n\mathbb{Z},1+m\mathbb{Z})$ in the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and conclude.